# Removing specific algorithms from Java security providers

Tags: java, tomcat, md5, java-security

I have a tomcat 7.x servlet container which deploys multiple war files from its `webapps` directory. I would like to make sure that none of these applications deployed in my tomcat use `MD5` algorithms. I can do that from java by:

```java
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for(Provider p : providers) {
  p.remove("MessageDigest.MD5");
}
```

However, this requires all web applications deployed in my tomcat to do the same. Is there anyway for me to do this just once, globally for this tomcat instance?

One possibility is to add it in a servlet init method, the configure the servlet to load on start up from global deployment descriptor.

I tried doing this, but in my tomcat instance, regardless of where I do this, the following lines never throw an exception:

```java
MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
hash.digest("ABCDEFGH".getBytes());
```

I was expecting it to throw `NoSuchAlgorithmException` since I removed `MessageDigest.MD5`. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Providers` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html):

> The service type Provider is reserved for use by the security
> framework. Services of this type cannot be added, removed, or modified
> by applications.

So you can remove a `Provider`, but you cannot remove a single service from a `Provider`.